# parse JSON Array with spaces in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to parse the below json array and get the values from it. But it is not working with spaces as values. I did find some solutions in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775462/jq-not-parsing-json-with-spaces) but nothing seems to work.

JSON

```
 {
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "Root Certification Authority - G2",
      "expiryDate": "Monday, 09 October 2023 20:03:25",
      "impactStatement": "Apps using this root certificate will have an actual impact",
      "notifyBeforeInDays": 60
    },
    {
      "name": "Bamboo",
      "expiryDate": "Sunday, 20 November 2022 03:25:23",
      "impactStatement": "CI/CD wont be working",
      "sop": "https://somelink/Bamboo+SOPs",
      "notifyBeforeInDays": 30
    },
    {
      "name": "Vault - Client",
      "expiryDate": "Monday, 09 October 2023 20:03:25",
      "impactStatement": "All Mule applications for that particular environment will stop working",
      "notifyBeforeInDays": 60
    },
    {
      "name": "Consul",
      "expiryDate": "Monday, 21 August 2023 14:43:56",
      "impactStatement": "No Direct impact or never had any such scenario so far",
      "notifyBeforeInDays": 30
    },
    {
      "name": "bitbucket",
      "expiryDate": "08 September 2021 13:16:06",
      "impactStatement": "No Impact",
      "notifyBeforeInDays": 15
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'm using the below code to parse the json

```
appls=$(awk '{print $0}' ${work_dir}/scripts/applications.json | jq -c '. |select(.apps !=null) |.apps[]')
echo "*****"
echo $appls
echo "*****"
for row in ${appls}; do
  echo $row
  validateAndNotify $row
done
```

And when i print the above variable following output is printed, which is not a valid one.

```
*****
 {"name":"bitbucket","expiryDate":"08 September 2021 13:16:06","impactStatement":"No Impact","notifyBeforeInDays":15} such scenario so far","notifyBeforeInDays":30}","notifyBeforeInDays":60}Bamboo+SOPs","notifyBeforeInDays":30}
*****
{"name":"Root
```

I want to parse the apps array and get each value inside that node.

Comment: btw that split is fully baroque, just `jq '.apps[]?' that/file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your variables in the shell to prevent from [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

work_dir="/foo/bar"

validateAndNotify() {
    echo "${1}"
}

appls=$(jq -c '.apps[]?' "${work_dir}/scripts/applications.json")

echo "*****"
echo "${appls}"
echo "*****"
while read -r row ; do
  validateAndNotify "${row}"
done <<< "${appls}"
```

PS: Shortened the jq command. Thanks [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014334/parse-json-array-with-spaces-in-bash/65014436#comment114941158_65014334)